# Increment number in URL address

Tags: linux, shell

I need help with my problem. I have url address for example `http://www.blabla.bla/forum-detail/?ft=72260&fid=34&&pgr=1` , where I want increment sequentially last number 1 to 786 and save in file. My result should look like this.

```
http://www.blabla.bla/forum-detail/?ft=72260&fid=34&&pgr=1
http://www.blabla.bla/forum-detail/?ft=72260&fid=34&&pgr=2
http://www.blabla.bla/forum-detail/?ft=72260&fid=34&&pgr=3
.
.
.
http://www.blabla.bla/forum-detail/?ft=72260&fid=34&&pgr=786
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you considered `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
$ seq 786 | sed 's@^@http://www.blabla.bla/forum-detail/?ft=72260\&fid=34\&\&pgr=@'
```

Or:

```
$ echo http://www.site.org/{1..10} | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Or:

```
$ printf 'http://www.site.org/%d\n' {1..10}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yes 'http://www.blabla.bla/forum-detail/?ft=72260&fid=34&&pgr=' |
 nl -ba | sed 786q | grep . | awk '{print $2$1}'
```

(The grep is there just for fun...)

Answer (score 0):

```
url="http://www.blabla.bla/forum-detail/?ft=72260&fid=34&&pgr=1"
for i in {1..786}; do
    echo "${url%1}$i"
done
```